# PHP array keep specified key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
$array = Array(
    '0' => Array('id' => '5', 'class' => 'A'),
    '1' => Array('id' => '53', 'class' => 'B'),
    '2' => Array('id' => '2', 'class' => 'C'),
);
```

I want if for example if class is 'B' to keep only key 1;

This is my code but it is not working correct:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    $array[$key]['description'] = 'dadadadad';
    if ($values['class'] == 'B') {
        $array = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(Array($key)));
    }

}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What's the point of `1 and ...`?

Comment: I can use array_filter but i don't understand why this is not working. The key is 1 but after that $array has wrong value.

Comment: 1 it is only for testing

Comment: @OsomA : I don't understand what's the purpose but `1 and` is useless cuz it's always return true.

Comment: Yep it is ok, but in my code 1 is another condition but i wanted to make code more clean.

Comment: It *does* work just fine: http://3v4l.org/lfKVr - the only thing is that you keep adding a `$array[2]['description']` regardless of your trimming the array.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$a = array_filter($a, function($item) {
  return $item['class'] === 'B';
});
```

According to the documentation, "array keys are preserved" when using array_filter.

Comment: Thank you, but i want to understand why my code it is not working.